# SQL Server 2008 - A Calculated Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, calculated-columns

I have two tables:

1) Streams

2) Comments

Inside Streams I want to create a Comments columns. I would like to have the Comments column in the Streams table calculated depending on how many Comments there are with the matching StreamId.

Is there an easy way to alter the current Streams table? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
-- be careful, I do asume lot of field names
create view withCount as
select s.*, c.cant 
from Streams s
left join 
   (select Streams_ID, count(*) as cant from Comments group by Streams_ID) as c
   on s.id = c.Streams_ID
```

And then

```
select * from withCount where ... order by ...  // or whatever you want
```

Do not use triggers to this task, they are more dificult to maintain and to understud

Comment: Nice this works perfectly. But I can now use withCount instead of the original table Streams? Since it has everything Streams does including the comment count. Right?

Comment: You can, but remember when you create a new field on Streams table, you need to recompile withCount view for it recognizes those new fields. And, Luis Siquot, very nice your mention about trigger problem with maintain in this case. It really is.

Comment: the simple anwser: you can use the view for selects instead of the table.  the complex anwser: you can create triggers on the view to manage deletes, updates and inserts (do not recomended also for this simple task) for this accions use the table directly.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a "real" column value, look at using a trigger.  Another option, though, might be a view that calculates this field -- it should be a really fast calculation if you're counting comments based on a primary key value.

Comment: Yeah I am calculating based on a PK. How can I create a View?